# Create a linux.img boot file when running with efi

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I'm trying to create a linux bootable file from the current linux system.

This is what I'm trying to arcive:

```
# (optional) update core.img (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Generate_core.img_alone )
grub-install --target=i386-pc --grub-setup=/bin/true --debug /dev/sda

# embed core.img into bootable file
cat /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/lnxboot.img /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img >/media/win/grub4bcd.img
```

The problem is that I'm booting from efi grub and not a bios grub in the mbr.
Then I don't have the lnxboot.img, core.img, i386-pc module, etc.

How can I create a linux boot file with my current system booting with efi?

I have read a lot and I can't figure our how to do this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok. I have just discovered the answered. I updated grup and during the update I selected to install grub on a usb drive. Then the i396-pc module was installed to do that.